# No HTTP request is performed at Google Maps web site when it displays autocompletable values. How is it possible?

Tags: ajax, http, firebug, inspect

I am using [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org) and [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in order to understand and learn how AJAX works. I am "inspecting" the [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com) web site and when I move to the search input field entering some names then it is displayed a list of autocompletable values. However, the strange thing is that any AJAX HTTP Request was performed in order to retrieve those values. *How is it possible?!* That is, how Google Maps'd retrieve those values?

*Note*: The same doesn't happen at the [Google](https://www.google.com) web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a problem with the way that you are using Firebug.
I checked it in Chrome Developer Tools, and I see an Ajax request every time I type a key, as you would expect.

Comment: You are right: with Chrome it works. Maybe I have some problem with Firebug but I cannot figure it out since Firebug works for all other web sites.

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox / Firebug, (Firefox 12 on OS X 10.8.2) and it works there too.